# Jetpack Compose navigation: login screen and different screen with bottom navigation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

My goal is to to have a `LoginScreen` from which I can navigate to an `InternalScreen`. The `InternalScreen` should have/be a bottom navigation bar that can navigate to multiple other screens/routes in the internal space.

This is what I imagined my `NavGraph` was supposed to look like:

```
 - LoginScreen
 - internal space
   - InternalScreen with BottomNavigation
     - some fragment
     - some other fragment
```

My idea was to create a `Scaffold` with a `BottomNavigationBar` in the `InternalScreen` composable but I do not no where to put it in my `NavGraph` since said `NavGraph` also has to contain the different routes for the `BottomNavigationBar`.

How should I approach this? I am sorry if this has already been answered, I couldn't find anything about this particular case.

Comment: you might wanna try following approach that seems doable in your case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvikKQkYGuc cmiiw

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the login screen/flow must be part of the application navigation flow.  In summary, your application must react to a `isLoggedIn` state, which should be global, and in case of the user is not logged in, the login screen must be displayed.

This is what I did:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainNavigation(
    viewModel: MainViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val auth = viewModel.auth
    val initialRoute =
        if (auth.isLoggedIn()) BooksFeature.route else LoginFeature.route

    AnimatedNavHost(
        navController,
        startDestination = initialRoute
    ) {
        loginGraph(auth, navController)
        booksGraph(auth, navController)
        settingsGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

The `MainNavigation` composable is the root of my app (which is called in `setContent` at `MainActivity`). Each feature of the app has a navigation graph. Like `booksGraph`:

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.booksGraph(
    auth: Auth, // this is a simple class which 
                // knows if the user is logged in
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    navigation(
        route = BooksFeature.route,
        startDestination = BooksList.route,
    ) {
        composable("ScreenA") {
            ScreenA()
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In my activity (I'm using just one activity), I'm observing the login state and redirecting to the login screen properly.

```kotlin
private fun launchLoginObserver() {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        mainViewModel.isLoggedIn.collect { isLoggedInState ->
            if (isLoggedInState == false) {
                navigationController.navigate(LoginScreen.route) {
                    popUpTo(0) // reset stack
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to take a look into the full implementation, here is the link for [my repository](https://github.com/nglauber/books_compose/).

Comment: This is what I feared I would have to to. Thank you for your detailed description

Comment: Does that mean, in this case, if we want a BottomTabBar after login, then we need to show and hide the visibility of it based on the screen we are on? i.e. hide it on Login and show it after the user logs in?